# Do we need to provide control permission with select permission to select data?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

What does control permission mean in SQL server 2008? When I provide only select permission it does not work i.e. user can't select but when I provide control + select permission then it is possible to select?

Comment: This problem is on the client application side. Try it in ssms it must work.

Comment: @Igor so you mean only select permission is enough ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CONTROL permission gives all other permissions except those explicitly denied. It's almost the same as ownership except that the owner can't be denied a permission.

Control + Select is meaningless, if you have control, then you have select permission anyway.